# How to get a popup to show up after 3 seconds but once per user using css and jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm new to using jQuery and am having trouble figuring out how to show a popup using css only once per user. I got the popup to work so that it shows up every time, I just need to only happen once per user.

My HTML Code

```
<div id="popUpMain" style="display: none;">
    <div id="popup">
      <h1 id="newsHeading">Join</h1>
      <a href="#linkHere" target="_blank"><button class="buttonNews">More Info</button></a>
      <button class="buttonNews">No Thanks</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The script handling the jQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
      $('#popUpMain').css('display', 'block'); }, 3000);
  });

  $('.buttonNews').click(function(){
    $('#popUpMain').css('display', 'none')
  });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is meant by "css only"? Because I think that phrase means something different to most people.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, phrasing: using css, only once per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to keep track of whether or not the user has been shown the popup before. The simplest way of doing this is by using `localStorage` to manage a boolean flag, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('popupPreviouslyShown') || false) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#popUpMain').css('display', 'block');
      localStorage.setItem('popupPreviouslyShown', true);
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nqu2s40k/)

Comment: This is perfect! Works great! Thanks for the response. I'll add it to solved once I can in 10 mins.